# mail.php not showing To, From or Subject when email is received

Tags: php, html, email

I have the code below which is working to some extent. The mail is received but the **To**, **From** and **Subject** fields are missing from the top of the email. They do however appear in the body.

[image]

Any ideas?

```
require_once "Mail.php";
$from = 'noreply@example.co.uk';
$to = 'recipient@example.co.uk';
$subject = 'registration';
$body = "<html>
<head>
<title>......</title>
</head>
Body text 
</html>";

$headers = array('MIME-Version' => "1.0",
'Content-type' => "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n\r\n",
'From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array('host' => 'mail.example.co.uk',
'port' => '25',
'auth' => true,
'username' => 'noreply@example.co.uk',
'password' => 'xxxxxx'
));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) 
{
echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
}
else
{
echo "Success";
}
```

**UPDATE**

If I remove the *'MIME-Version' => "1.0", 'Content-type' => "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n\r\n",* lines I see the details as I should but I obviously lose the html formatting.

View Source on received email:

```
From: noreply@example.co.uk
To: recipient@exmaple.co.uk
Subject: registration

<html>
....
</html>
```

Comment: Could you may post any mails source code as you receive?

Comment: see edit ... is that what you meant?

Comment: did you try moving mime and content type pieces to the end of the array? Sometimes php is picky about order.

Comment: Brilliant - so simple!! If you post as an answer I will accept